# Prefer some MySql Optimization techniques for Bulk data table

Tags: php, mysql, join, query-optimization, left-join

i faced the problem on query processing for large amount of data in MySql. i need to fetch data into more than four tables by join function . the query runs very slowly on server .

how to optimize the processing time for multiple join queries.

I am currently using the innodb engine . It is ok for bulk data table .

i have tables like

Data in those tables **exam,students,subjects,subject_tests,subject_test_mark,total_subject,**

i get all students record of current exam .

This will previously process by multiple for loops . continuous db access . That a reason to slow down my process . how to avoid these scenarios by SQL . Suggest me some ideas that are welcome .

i have some doubts on this . Table engine innodb is fine or not  . Indexing is support for this process or not ?

```
SELECT `sub`.student_id,
((sum( `sub`.total / `main`.max_total )) / count( sub.id )) *10 AS percent,
GROUP_CONCAT((sub.total / main.max_total) *10 ORDER BY (sub.total / main.max_total) *10 DESC SEPARATOR ',' ) AS marks
FROM 
`cmark_batch` AS `main`
LEFT JOIN `cmark_para_total` AS `sub` 
ON `sub`.mark_batch_id = `main`.id
WHERE main.batch_id =29
AND main.term =4
AND main.subject_id =64
AND main.status = 'A'
GROUP BY student_id

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  main    ref     search  search  8   const   85  Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  sub     ref     finder  finder  8   newlive.main.id     14  NULL
```

```
SELECT t1.mark_batch_id, t1.id, t1.param_name, t1.max_mark,t2.student, t2.mark
FROM `cmark_parameter` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `cmark_parameter_mark` AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.mark_parameter_id
WHERE t1.mark_batch_id
IN (621,620,623,622)
AND t1.status = 'A'
AND t2.status = 'A'
ORDER BY `t2`.`student` ASC

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  t2  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    78835   Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  t1  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     8   newlive.t2.cmark_parameter_id   1   Using where
```

```
SELECT t1.student_id, t1.mark_batch_id, t1.total
FROM `cmark_para_total` AS t1
WHERE t1.mark_batch_id
IN (621,620,623,622)
AND t1.status = 'A'
ORDER BY `t1`.`id` ASC


id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  t1  range   finder  finder  8   NULL    111     Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: InnoDB is fine, indexing is definitely supported. Post your actual SQL query, and your table structure so we can help you. An explenation of "the query flow" isn't good enough in this case.

Comment: thanks @Tularis i can't upload image for the table structure here my reputation low. soon i edit

Comment: @RyanBabu Do I understand correctly: the result of your flow in the paragraph beginning with "Flow:" will be processed by a series of querys, fired up in nested loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the keyword 'EXPLAIN' to determine what is causing the slowness and what you can do to optimize.

More here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use database caching to reduce the time of loading complex queries. 
In the Mysql manual is a description how you can enable database caching:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

In your query you have to add the attribute SQL_CACHE to enable caching, example:

SELECT SQL_CACHE id, name FROM customer;